# Give dockerized shiny application access to local volumes

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile

I have a shiny application which I have containerised with Docker. Within the shiny application I use the `shinyFiles` library to allow the user to choose and upload a directory.

My server.R file looks something like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) {
    volumes <- c("Home (~)" = '~', "Current directory" = getwd(), "Root (/)" = '/')
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'resultsLocation', roots=volumes, session=session)
})
```

and my ui.R file looks something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    shinyDirButton('resultsLocation', 'Browse...', title = 'Select a directory')
))
```

This is fine if I run the app locally through R, however, if I build and run the docker container, the user cannot access their local volumes, and instead are stuck within the docker container.

I followed [this](https://www.bjoern-bos.de/post/learn-how-to-dockerize-a-shinyapp-in-7-steps/) guide to set up my docker container (with the addition of running `chmod +x shiny-server.sh` to make the file executable) and everything other than the volumes is working. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Install R version 3.6.0
FROM r-base:3.6.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer (latest version)
RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinyFiles')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 3838
# EXPOSE 3838

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

# Allow permissions
RUN chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

And I build and run the container with:

```
docker build -t shiny_docker_test . ; docker run -p 3838:3838 shiny_docker_test
```

So, my question is: how can I access my local filesystem/volumes through the dockerised shiny app with shinyFiles? I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I am new to all of this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use docker volume feature. For example:
In command line -v is used to map container directories with host directories

> docker -v full_path_on_host:full_path_inside_container

Similarly, there is VOLUME keyword for same stuff while working on docker file.

Comment: So if I was to add `-v $HOME:$HOME` to the `docker run` command it works, but how do I do this within the Dockerfile?

Comment: @oska where you able solve you problem or should I help you out further?

Comment: I was able to do what you suggested and upload files using -v `$HOME:/srv/shiny-server/home`, and then in the server.R file, I change the home volume to be `"Home (~)" = "/srv/shiny-server/home"`. However, in my app, I save things to the home directory (e.g. `pdf("/srv/shiny-server/home/plot.pdf", ...)`) and it and this doesnt seem to work. It might be a permission issue, but I dont know how to tell. I know this is a slightly different question, but I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can ssh into the docker container using docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash

Comment: Once you are inside the container, you can try creating files there, once using super user, and once using application user, I am sure your application does not have permission to create files there, and the ones you will create manually would reflect outside.

Comment: Ah great, thank you. It works, so its probably not a permission issue, but that alone helps a lot. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Does this also work if you read daily data from Google Drive? –